# How to use enums for typing in typescript

Tags: typescript, enums, typescript-typings

i'm a bit confused on how to use Enums with TS. Can you use an enum as a value instead of a type?
i tried many different ways but i couldn't solve it.
Here's my code but it doesn't seem to typeCheck it:

This is the interface.ts

```
//interface.ts
export enum EMadeFrom {
  'stripe',
  'manually',
  'app',
  'invoice.payment_succeeded',
  'customer.subscription.updated.trial',
  'customer.subscription.updated.active',
}
export interface IPayments {
  modelID: string
  amount: number
  paymentMethod: string
  paymentMethodType: string
  productType: string
  stripeCustomerId: string
  stripePaymentStatus: string
  stripeId: string
  stripePriceId: Array<string>
  stripeSubscriptionStartDate: string
  stripeSubscriptionEndDate: string
  sessionPhoto: ISessionPhoto | null
  madeFrom: EMadeFrom
  createdAt: Date
  updatedAt: Date
}
```

the route:

```
const CUSTOMER_SUBSCRIPTION_UPDATED_TRIAL =
                  'customer.subscription.updated.trial'
                try {
                  const payment = await modelModel.createPayment(
                    model.id,
                    stripeInvoice.total / 100,
                    stripeCustomer.invoice_settings.default_payment_method,
                    'card',
                    productIsBundle ? BUNDLE : SUBSCRIPTION, 
                    subscriptionUpdated.customer, 
                    subscriptionUpdated.status, 
                    subscriptionUpdated.id, 
                    subscriptionUpdated.plan.id, 
                    stripeSubscriptionStartDate,
                    stripeSubscriptionEndDate,
                    sessionPhoto,
                    CUSTOMER_SUBSCRIPTION_UPDATED_TRIAL,
                  )
```

and my createPayment function:

```
const createPayment = (
  modelId: IPayments['modelID'],
  amount: IPayments['amount'],
  paymentMethod: IPayments['paymentMethod'],
  paymentMethodType: IPayments['paymentMethodType'],
  productType: IPayments['productType'],
  stripeCustomerId: IPayments['stripeCustomerId'],
  stripePaymentStatus: IPayments['stripePaymentStatus'],
  stripeId: IPayments['stripeId'],
  stripePriceId: IPayments['stripePriceId'],
  stripeSubscriptionStartDate: IPayments['stripeSubscriptionStartDate'],
  stripeSubscriptionEndDate: IPayments['stripeSubscriptionEndDate'],
  sessionPhoto: null | IPayments['sessionPhoto'],
  madeFrom: IPayments['madeFrom'],
) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `CUSTOMER_SUBSCRIPTION_UPDATED_TRIAL` as this:

```
const CUSTOMER_SUBSCRIPTION_UPDATED_TRIAL = 'customer.subscription.updated.trial';
```

This is a **string**, not a member of your `EMadeFrom` enum. You can convert it to the type of `EMadeFrom` by indexing into it:

```
EMadeFrom[CUSTOM_SUBSCRIPTION_UPDATED_TRIAL]; // gives correct value
```

So you would call your function like this, actually:

```
const payment = await modelModel.createPayment(
    model.id,
    stripeInvoice.total / 100,
    stripeCustomer.invoice_settings.default_payment_method,
    'card',
    productIsBundle ? BUNDLE : SUBSCRIPTION, 
    subscriptionUpdated.customer, 
    subscriptionUpdated.status, 
    subscriptionUpdated.id, 
    subscriptionUpdated.plan.id, 
    stripeSubscriptionStartDate,
    stripeSubscriptionEndDate,
    sessionPhoto,
    EMadeFrom[CUSTOMER_SUBSCRIPTION_UPDATED_TRIAL],
)
```